# Issues with my Dependent Variable consisting of ~95% zeros

Tags: regression, zero-inflation

I'm currently struggling with my hurdle-regression analysis. My sample consists of randomly selected people in my hometown. The sample size is around 600 participants. My DV (count of car thefts) has way too many zeros (~95%), so my IVs only become insignificant (very large SEs) whatever I do. Since these zeros are true values, I have to use my DV as it is. Log or other scale transformations don't get me different results.

I know that this is reality, but I need some advice how I can explain these results as they are in my paper. Is there any literature out there that has addressed this issue

Many thanks in advance!

BTW I use Stata (churdle command)

Comment: As a rule of thumb, because the minority class in this dataset is only about 30 observations, you can expect to estimate only one, perhaps two coefficients.  How many IVs do you have?

Comment: @whuber In total I use 6 variables plus two interaction terms.

Comment: Then that's more than your data can support.